# Asp.Net How to add a decimal point to a string

Tags: asp.net

If I have a string/integer that looks like `123`, how can I convert that to look like `12.3`?

Basically what I need is something faster (if possible) than this

```
Math.Round(Double.Parse(input / 1000), 1).ToString
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an integer do:

```
double value = (double)integer / 10.0;
string output = value.ToString();
```

If it's a string then you need to convert it to an integer first:

```
int integer = Int32.Parse(input);
```

If you're not sure that the string is an integer:

```
bool isInt = Int32.TryParse(input, out integer);
```